# Is it possible to create a views programmatically and name them with the value of a string?

Tags: java, android, view

I want to add an indefinite number of views to another view. How many views are needed depends on a variable. I don't want it to have a limit. And want their names to be in a series (using incrementing values of a string maybe). Is it possible to do this programmatically?

I'm new to programming. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do that.  Views are expensive, adding large numbers of them will either slow your app to a crawl or crash it OOM, if not both.  Look into RecyclerView as an alternative to doing that.  RecyclerViews reuse and rebind a limited number of views, allowing for scrolling between them with a minimal number of views used.

A technique of adding views is acceptable if the number of views is small (as is their screen real estate) and has a cap.  In that case you can programmatically add views to a ViewGroup with the add function.  But you can't give it a name.  You could give it an id, but that's not recommended.  And it shouldn't really be necessary-  since you created it, you shouldn't need to look it up in the view hierarchy again, which is the major reason to give a name to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable.

If you want to display a list with dynamic size, you can use `RecyclerView` to implement.

If you don't want to display a list, you can use `addView()` method of ViewGroup, or use `WindowManager` to add view dynamically.

```
val windowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
windowManager.addView(yourView, layoutParamsForThisView)
```

Comment: You haven't covered setting a custom id for view. Personally, I do not remember either is it possible to add this custom id or not, but the view is possible to query ```LayoutContainer```, it returns all views inside itself as an array.